# How to use Coq GenericMinMax to prove facts about the reals

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove

```
Theorem T20d :forall (x y:R), (0<x /\ 0<y) -> 0 < Rmin x y.
```

with

```
Lemma min_glb_lt n m p : p < n -> p < m -> p < min n m.
```

which is in  Coq.Structures.GenericMinMax

which I imported with Require Import Coq.Structures.GenericMinMax

however, I still get "reference min_glb_lt" not found when I try to use it? I suspect I need to open a scope, but I don't know which scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the [`GenericMinMax`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.GenericMinMax.html) library defines *generic* structures, so you can't use them directly to solve a *concrete* problem. That library mostly contains functors. In other words, it provides interfaces which you need to implement to be able to use them.

In our case, we need to implement the [`MinMaxLogicalProperties`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.GenericMinMax.html#GenericMinMax) functor (or some other functor that includes this one), because it includes the required lemma.

Several Coq standard libraries provide such implementations. Luckily for us, it has already been done for the reals in the file [`Rminmax.v`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Rminmax.html), inside the module [`R`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Rminmax.html#R), this line specifically:

```
Include UsualMinMaxProperties R_as_OT RHasMinMax.
```

So, we can use it like so:

```
Require Import Reals.
Require Import Rminmax. Import R.

Local Open Scope R_scope.

Theorem T20d (x y : R) :
   (0 < x /\ 0 < y) -> 0 < Rmin x y.
Proof.
  intros [? ?].
  now apply min_glb_lt.
Qed.
```

Alternatively, we could've referred to the lemma by its qualified name `R.min_glb_lt` -- that would've let us get rid of `Import R`.

Comment: Why `Include` and not `Import` in this case ?

Comment: It's a copy-paste artifact :) `Import` works as well. Thanks for spotting that.